# Add dates of a month in same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I want to auto-populate the dates of a month in the excel sheet.

**Requirements**

1. If I change the month from September to October , it should add the weekend. For example, the 10th and 11th of September 2022 are Saturday and Sunday. So these should be added along with the dates. (Sun or Sunday is OK)
2. The weekends has to be highlighted automatically while selecting the month and year.

[image]

The above screenshot illustrates the expected result for the month of September 2022. If I change the month to October in A1 and the Year to 2024, the Days corresponding to the dates (Monday, Tuesday , ... Sunday) should change accordingly.

Comment: "The requirement is to have the weekends", but you only show one weekend on your image, why? Where are the others? Why is 11 September 2022 is shown on the image as Monday instead of Sunday (unless your calendar is another year)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have edited the question with proper screenshot, and added more explanation. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the range from that must highlighted. Then create a conditional formatting rule that use the following formula

```
=OR(WEEKDAY(B$1)=1,WEEKDAY(B$1)=7)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks providing the highlight part but the answer only help with the highlighting section. The basic requirement is auto populating the days based on the month and year.

Comment: @JoelDeleep If you have a calendar as you stated in the OP, then the requirement is to highlight the cells. As the date or months change, it will be done automatically.  Mine works https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFfSt.gif

Comment: I created a calendar this way. A10 holds the year, B10 the month. in A1, put the formula `=DATE(A10,B10,1)`, set the format to `mmmm`. In B1, formula `=A1`. In C1, formula: `IF(B1+1>EOMONTH(B1,0),"",B1+1)`. Drag it to fill the cells up to 31st cell. B2, C2, etc have the same formula, except their format is `ddd`. Try the same.

Comment: That makes it right, I think I messed with the question, also if the month is february it will create error, so for the last three cells, it has to be =IFERROR(IF(AC1+1>EOMONTH(AC1,0),"",AC1+1),"")